# C/C++ error highlighting from make?

Tags: c++, colors, terminal, makefile

When the C/C++ compiler gives me warnings or errors, its very hard to filter them. Is there some simple terminal program or script to highlight them?

Now they look like

```
lk@minetoo ~/proj/mgi2 $ make
g++ -lpthread -o mgi.r mgi.cpp
In file included from mgi.cpp:19:0:
paux.hpp:101:1: error: expected class-name before '{' token
paux.hpp:104:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '}' token
mgi.cpp: In constructor 'Server::Server()':
mgi.cpp:73:57: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
mgi.cpp:78:84: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
mgi.cpp: In member function 'int Server::run()':
mgi.cpp:84:62: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
mgi.cpp:92:52: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
make: *** [mgi] Error 1
```

Comment: You see color because of stackoverflow, but on terminal it is plain. and REALLY hard to filter.

Comment: What would you expect in the filtered out error?

Comment: Filter with my eyes. It all is one piece of white pixels, curves, straights in my eyes on the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [`colorgcc`](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html) for this. It works pretty well.

Comment: You're on Gentoo? It could be a problem with your `PS1` variable. What shell are you using?

Comment: True. I am on Gentoo. Nice! Bash. `\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[01;34m\] \w \$\[\033[00m\]`

Comment: Odd, even with that `PS1` I get nice perty colors: http://i.imgur.com/bVomA.png. I'm on Arch Linux with XFCE, which might cause things to work differently.

Comment: I am on a i3wm session with xterms and some custom color config. That is: `alias xterm -bg black -fg gray`, which should not cause any mistakes. xterm itself? When i login from another machine with `gnome-termianl` via SSH, still everything red.

Comment: Yes. I am a hobby C/C++ programmer, and i even managed to install gentoo! I know that =P. I am being proposed to move this to chat... `Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?`

Comment: It's a cold-hearted machine (if you have more than 5-6 comments SO will nag you), but you don't have to listen to it ;) It could be a version mismatch between `gcc` and `colorgcc`. I'm using `gcc 4.6.2` and `colorgcc 1.3.2`, so maybe Gentoo might provide different packages than Arch.

Comment: Gentoo has gcc 4.6 hardmasked. i have thus 4.5.3-r1 and colorgcc 1.3.2-r4. I am sorry but what does that matter? I guess even microsoft compilers or java compilers generate similar text outputs. How do you invoke it? Me: `make | colorgcc`

Comment: `export CC="colorgcc"`. It wraps around `gcc`.

Comment: Also, look at the README for the project on GitHub: https://github.com/johannes/colorgcc

Answer (score 2):

You could try [colorgcc](https://github.com/johannes/colorgcc) (it colors errors in red, etc.)

Comment: Too much red =P. Check the comment-conversation in Blender's answer